# .htaccess for Subdomain and Subfolder w/SSL

Tags: htaccess, subdomains

I have the htaccess from wordpress codex for a subdomain.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

but the wordpress installation is in a subfolder of the subdomain. I am confused how to create the correct htaccess file.

Comment: how is SSL relevant here? What is the exact problem? why do you modify the htaccess generated by wordpress?

Comment: As @MarkKaplun stated. Also, What is your website pointing to now and what do you expected it to be?

Comment: I just ended up using just subdomain with the htaccess info above. Having a subdomain and subfolder with wordpress causes problems with .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Typically if your subdomain's root is the folder with WP installed, then just create a .htaccess file there. That always works for me.
Example:

```
public_html -> 
   random
   etc..
   mywpfolder (the wp folder)
      wp-admin
      wp-content
      etc..
      .htaccess (create htaccess file here or simply copy/paste the primary one here)
```

**EDIT**

Do you have the other installs in your domain root or the subfolder root? In any case adding the htaccess file to the folder that has your wp-admin, wp-content, etc should work for that WordPress install - it shouldn't affect other installs. Unless I misunderstood your question.

Comment: There is other installations in the root.